# How to diagnose stalls when writing to a `TUN` device?

Tags: linux, rust, libc

**EDIT**: This may be an issue with `tun` library I'm using https://github.com/yaa110/async-tun/issues/2

I am learning about linux networking and trying to build a simple VPN tunnel using `libp2p`. The code I have is capable of forwarding traffic between peers using virtual `tun` devices to capture packets and the p2p transport to send each packet. The problem is that flushing the buffer for the `tun` device often stalls, usually for 30+ seconds, sometimes forever.

I'm really confused by this and don't know how to debug further. My only guess is that device is busy, but I'm not sure how to tell if this is the case, and if it is the case then I'm not sure why. It doesn't look like my code can deadlock because I'm using `select!` but maybe I am totally misunderstanding what I've instructed the computer to do.

The relevant part of the code is below and the context can be viewed [here](https://github.com/littlebenlittle/p2p-tun/blob/47a9745276c33730816db4ccc368449f1f9589f0/src/main.rs#L104).

```rs
use async_std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufReader, BufWriter},
}
// ...
let mut packet = [0u8; MTU];
let mut tun_reader: BufReader<&File> = tun.reader();
let mut tun_writer: BufWriter<&File> = tun.writer()
loop {
    select! {
        _ = tun_reader.read(&mut packet).fuse() => {
            if let Some(peer_id) = handle_tun_packet(packet, &routing_table) {
                swarm
                    .behaviour_mut()
                    .request_response
                    .send_request(&peer_id, packet);
            }
        }
        event = swarm.select_next_some() => match event {
            SwarmEvent::Behaviour(Event::RequestResponse(RequestResponseEvent::Message {
                peer,
                message: RequestResponseMessage::Request { request, .. },
            })) => {
                let request: [u8; MTU] = request;  // packet
                if handle_peer_packet(request, &routing_table, &peer).await? {
                    let n = tun_writer.write(&request).await?;
                    tun_writer.flush().await?;
                    // stalls???
               }
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have reproducible code so I can only guess, but maybe you're using blocking operations and blocking the `select!`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @ChayimFriedman. I'm looking into a different way to handle the reader/writer by spawning different tasks for each. The challenge with that is that both methods borrow the underlying file descriptor of the tun. I probably need to use a mutex?